SQL Database - how to design entities to make search operations faster?
I need to design some database entities to store logged events.
The events have several properties, among which the message.  This message is actually coming from a limited set of templates, with variable number of parameters, and different values filled-in for those parameters from one logged event to another. Example:
System was restarted.
User <user-name> has logged off.
User <user-name> has assigned the device <device-name> from group <group-1> to group <group-2>.

One challenge is that I need to offer the Search function, including search by content of the message.
Question: how should I design the entities for this ?

one-table for everything, that would hold the message directly filled-in with parameters values ?

Or, alternatively
2.
- one events table, FK to a message-templates table
- a params table with param-name, param-value entries, FK to the events table ?
Which of these would get me a better search performance (especially considering that the DB would G R O W in time) ?


Which of these would get me a better search performance

Depends on your queries but usually simply approach option 1 (one-table for everything) is faster. Shred it to extract details (parameters) in separate fields
Some other notes: if you are responsible for all log sources, I mean ALL entries are following templates you don't need to keep human readable message.

(especially considering that the DB would G R O W in time)

You don't need to keep it all in RDBMS. You should partition your table by event_time and drop older partitions or archive them as external files.

In my opinion you are trying to store logs into an RDBMS.
Logs should be sored on log files instead on a file system. They are like images, they have to be stored in a file system and not in a database.
You will end up soring those logs into an NVARCHAR(MAX) or let's say NVARCHAR(500) and your DB will just become havier and havier.
I give you two options:

RDBMS, not optimal solution: Store it in a table that has these columns: datetime, message, user-name, device-name, group-1, group-2. But probably you will add more columns and it will become a mess. Or maybe you can just have a table with datetime and message but in this case you will always search using WHERE datetime = '' AND message LIKE ''. And this is the contrary of good practice and good performance. and forget about using FK on that table
NoSQL, better solution: We created NoSQL databases exactly for this situation. Just store the Logs in a File System. Ingest the logs through Elasticsearch or MongoDB or whatever NoSQL engine on top of it and dive into the logs through that.

